# Symlinking folders in bash

Tags: bash, unix, symlink

I want a folder `/public_html` to symlink to `/current/app/webroot`, both are in the same directory

I have tried

```
ln -s public_html current/app/webroot
```

amongst other things, but no joy so far.  Any ideas?

Comment: Clippy: "It seems, that you want to map the docroot to a symlink. Have you checked, that your server follows symlinks?"

Comment: "No joy" is not an error message. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `public_html` to be a symlink to somewhere else, you need to write the "somewhere else" first and the target second:

```
ln -s `pwd`/current/app/webroot public_html
```

Also, if you already have a normal `public_html` directory, you need to remove that first.

(Also, what Clippy said above.)

Comment: As the order of ln's arguments confuse a lot of people: It's the same order you use with cp - first the thing you have, than the thing you want.

Answer (score 1):

You needed to check `ln` man

```
   ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)
   ln [OPTION]... TARGET                  (2nd form)
   ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)
   ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET...  (4th form)
```

First target, then link name

In case of

```
/some/directory/
  current/
    app/
      webroot/
  public_html -> current/app/webroot
```

you need to do this

```
`ln -s current/app/webroot public_html`
```

It's not mandatory for `ln` to give absolute paths, relative ones work too

Comment: @user343223: You should select Dmitry's answer if you're happy with it.